# How to show only interfaces starting with a certain pattern

Tags: regular-expression, network-interface, ifconfig, virtual-interface

Open-Vswitch creates virtual interfaces, they all have this pattern: `s[digit]-eth[digit]` For example: `s1-eth1, s1-eth2, s12-eth3, s2-eth3 ...`

I want to show information of *-for example-* all interfaces starting with s1 (in our example, it must give `s1-eth1` and `s1-eth2)`.

I tried this command, but it shows only the first line of information:

### [image]

I am more interested about information like `RX packets, TX packets, erros, HWaddr..` like this:

[image]

Comment: `ifconfig` will give you different output depending on what distro you're running. Consider using `ip` instead.

Comment: [Please don't post text as images](https://unix.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4086/psa-please-dont-post-images-of-text)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For your current `ifconfig` output:

```
ifconfig | grep -A7 --no-group-separator '^s1-eth'
```

Answer (score 7):

`ifconfig`'s output has a blank line between each interface, making it perfectly suited for reading and processing in "paragraph mode" in a scripting language like `awk` or `perl`.  A "paragraph" is any block of text separated from other blocks by one-or-more empty lines.

For example:

```
ifconfig | awk -v RS='' '/^s1-eth[12]:/ {print}'
```

The `awk` example above sets `awk`'s record separator (`RS`) to the empty string, causing it to process paragraphs instead of individual lines.  In this case, each paragraph is tested for a match against `^s1-eth[12]:` and is printed if it matches.

Example output from my system:

```
$ ifconfig | awk -v RS='' '/^(ppp0|lo):/ {print}'
lo: flags=73<UP,LOOPBACK,RUNNING>  mtu 65536
        inet 127.0.0.1  netmask 255.0.0.0
        loop  txqueuelen 1000  (Local Loopback)
        RX packets 64237556  bytes 36962222928 (34.4 GiB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 64237556  bytes 36962222928 (34.4 GiB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
ppp0: flags=4305<UP,POINTOPOINT,RUNNING,NOARP,MULTICAST>  mtu 1412
        inet ip.ip.ip.ip  netmask 255.255.255.255  destination ip.ip.ip.ip
        ppp  txqueuelen 3  (Point-to-Point Protocol)
        RX packets 28220997  bytes 19305565357 (17.9 GiB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 21719890  bytes 3009382446 (2.8 GiB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
```

Note that this is no longer printed in paragraphs - there is no empty line between each interfaces "record".  If you want paragraphs in your output, set the output record separator (`ORS`) to two newlines (`\n\n`).  e.g.

```
ifconfig | awk -v RS='' -v ORS='\n\n' '/^(ppp0|lo):/ {print}'
```

---

To do something similar with `ip`'s output rather than `ifconfig`'s is slightly more complicated.  `ip` doesn't produce neatly paragraph-separated output.  It does, however, output each interface in a block with the interface's number followed by a colon and a space at the beginning of a line, with the rest of that interfaces details following.

To make use of this, set RS to the regular expression (`(^|\n)[0-9]+:`).  That matches any digits followed by a colon and a space (`[0-9]+:`) that are *either* at the beginning of the file (`^`, to match the first record, which would otherwise be skipped) or immediately after a newline.

For example, on my system:

```
$ ip addr | awk -v RS='(^|\n)[0-9]+: ' '/^(lo|eth0):/ {print}'
lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
    inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
eth0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast master br0 state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 01:33:ed:b0:13:a9 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
```

(my `eth0` doesn't have any IP addresses because I have it set up as a bridge for VMs and docker containers.  The IP addresses are on the `br0` interface instead)

Answer (score 4):

You could use `grep -An` to print the matching line and the *n* following ones, but that is a bit untidy since the number of lines may vary.

Probably better to use `awk`. This would print all sections that start with `enp1` or `enp3`. The first rule `!/^ / {p=0}` clears the variable `p` if the line does not start with a space, the second `/^enp[13]/ {p=1}` sets if it the line starts with the interface names we want, and then we print if `p` is set. The lines that start with spaces only match the last rule, so they're printed based on the previous value of `p`.

```
# /sbin/ifconfig -a  |awk '!/^ / {p=0} /^enp[13]/ {p=1}; p'
enp1s0    Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr ... 
          inet addr:...
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:135284106 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:144695 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:2
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:8292624956 (8.2 GB)  TX bytes:16595674 (16.5 MB)
enp3s0    Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr ...  
          BROADCAST MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:0 (0.0 B)  TX bytes:0 (0.0 B)
```

In your case, you'd of course use a pattern like `/^s1-eth/`.

Answer (score 3):

> I want to show information of -for example- all interfaces starting with `s1`

Using `net-tools`:

```
ifconfig | grep s1 -A9
```

Using `iproute2`:

```
ip -s link | grep s1 -A7
```

Answer (score 0):

For post-processing, with newer versions of `iproute2` you may want to use the JSON output format that is meant for that:

```
ip -j -s link show |
  jq -r '
    .[]|
    select(.ifname|test("^s\\d+-eth\\d+$"))|
    [.ifname, .stats64.rx.bytes, .stats64.tx.bytes]|
    @csv'
```

For instance to get a CSV output with interface name, RX and TX bytes.

Answer (score -2):

```
 ifconfig | awk '/^s[[:digit:]]+-eth[[:digit:]]+:/ {flag=1} /!^[[:digit:]]+-eth[[:digit:]]+:/ {flag=0}flag'
```

Using awk, pattern match to as outlined, setting a print flag to 1 if it exists and 0 if not. Print based on flag.

Comment: While the approach is valid, you don't seem to have tested that script at all.

Answer (score -2):

Previous answers suggested:

`ifconfig`: which is deprecated.

`ip -s link`: which doesn't display all the information that `ifconfig` displays (such as IP address).

I wanted to offer another command that worked for me. So if you're looking for IP address(es) of an interface, you might consider:

For the raw interface output:

```
ip a | grep s1 -A3
```

For IPv4 only:

```
ip -4 a | grep s1 -A1
```

`ip a` is an abbrevation for `ip address`. `-A1` and `-A3` paremeters determine the number of lines to display after the last occurrence of your text. If you modify the parameters in `ip` command, you can change the `-A` parameter's number to fit as well.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Can you expand on your answer so that it is evident how it is different from some of the other answers that also suggest using `ip` (or `ifconfig`) together with `grep`?